# Minification failed. Returning unminified contents when contain template literals

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, template-literals

I'm using asp.net mvc .Net framework 4.6.2. 
I have a test.js file with this content:

```
function ThisIsTestFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        //will do some test
        let b = i + 10;
        let c = b / 2;
        var str = `My name is ${a + c}`;
    }
}
```

Checking network response for this file bundle on debug=false I get:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(6,19-20): run-time error JS1014: Invalid character: `
(6,23-27): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';': name
(6,39-40): run-time error JS1014: Invalid character: `
 */
function ThisIsTestFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        //will do some test
        let b = i + 10;
        let c = b / 2;
        var str = `My name is ${a + c}`;
    }
};
```

If I delete the line with the template literals (

> "var str = `My name is ${a + c}`;"

) the bundle minification works! So I understand that the minification engine doesn't like/know how to deal with that.
What are my options with minifications when the js scripts contains template literals?

Comment: What are you using to minify? What is the config of this minification?

Comment: Mvc bundle optimization. "System.Web.Optimization;" didn't config it.

Comment: Maybe `System.Web.Optimization` doesn't understand template strings? Consider using another minification tool?

Comment: There's a duplicate question, but it has no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934252/microsoft-aspnet-web-optimization-javascript-bundling-fails-to-minify-template-l